# Recycler view не обновляет данные до тех пор, пока не скролишь

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Делаю простенький чат. Столкнулся с проблемой: при отправке нового сообщения отсутствует изменения данных в Recycler View, который выступает в роли списка сообщений. Этот список обновляется, как только я начинаю его скроллить или скрываю клавиатуру. Немного погуглил, попробовал пару способов исправить это. Ничего присутствующее в коде ниже не исправило мою проблему :( 
Вот, собственно, сам код:
(В этот метод приходит json c новым сообщением и я его вношу в список)

```
@Override
public void onFrame(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame frame) throws Exception {
    Log.i("fg", "onFrame");
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(frame.getPayloadText());
    if(data.has("data")) {
        MyMessage myMessage = new MyMessage(data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("data"),
                data.getString("login"), data.getString("unix_time"), data.getString("user_id"), data.getString("avatar"));
        adapter.addToStart(myMessage, true);
        adapter.update(myMessage);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount());

}
```

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` работает только с коллекциями, переданными в конструктор адаптера.

Comment: Судя по названию `adapter.addToStart(myMessage, true);` Вы добавили `item` в начало списка, а адаптеру говорите что в конец, может надо так: `adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);`

Comment: Так проблема в том, что список именно не обновляется? Или он обновляется, но где-то сверху и нужно чтобы он автоматически проскролился? Добавьте код методов адаптера `addToStart` и `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После добавления `item`-a также необходимо `recyclerView` проскроллить програмно. У себя делаю так

```
messagesRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
```

Comment: А можно ли обновлять список без скролла?
Когда приходит сообщение от собеседника, лист сообщений тоже скроллится, чего, естественно, не должно быть.
Буду благодарен любым вашим идеям!